# Merge two tables with indepented columns as a result

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010

I have two tables

First Table

```
id  f1
1   a
1   b   
2   c
3   d
3   e
```

Second Table

```
id  f2  
1   k
2   m
2   n
3   p
```

And I want

```
id  f1  f2
1   a   k
1   b   
2   c   m
2       n
3   d   p
3   e
```

As a result is a table with two independent columns (f1 and f2) that shared one reference column (id) and when a column (f1 or f2) has a smaller number of records with the same code then the cells are empty.

Comment: At first glance this looked like a simple INNER JOIN but it seems not.  What's the logic behind rows in the results like `1, b, (empty)` instead of `1, b, k`, and `2, (empty), n` instead of `2, c, n`?

Comment: The tables ara in Access. But if there is not solution then I will transfer them is Sql Server if there is a solution there.

Comment: ARC Yes but it is not related to the problem. The order simply makes the requested more distinct

Comment: squillman I have already added more explanations

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In SQL Server, you can use the `row_number` window function to generate another column that can be used to join the two tables.

I'm not familiar enough with Access to know whether it supports window functions or if there is an access-specific equivalent.

```sql
     -- your data tables
with t1 as (select * from (values (1,'a'),(1,'b'),(2,'c'),(3,'d'),(3,'e')) t(id,f1))
    ,t2 as (select * from (values (1,'k'),(2,'m'),(2,'n'),(3,'p')        ) t(id,f2))

     -- your data with sequence counter for each ID
    ,t1Seq as (select *, seq = row_number() over (partition by id order by f1) from t1)
    ,t2Seq as (select *, seq = row_number() over (partition by id order by f2) from t2)

-- generate your desired rowset by using a full join
-- on the id and the generated sequence number within each id value
select id = coalesce(t1Seq.id,t2Seq.id)
      ,t1Seq.f1
      ,t2Seq.f2
from           t1Seq
     full join t2Seq on t2Seq.id = t1Seq.id and t2Seq.seq = t1Seq.seq
;
```

Comment: MS-Access doesn't support `row_number`, `coalesce` functions.